# firebase package not working using angular 12

Tags: angular, firebase

hi i tried to use `firebase` with my `angular` application, i installed `firebase` package by command `npm install firebase @angular/fire --save` , when i import `AngularFireModule` it gives me error: `Unable to evaluate this expression statically`.

[image]

```
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';

 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule

  ],
```

**environement.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyC5Zpt1sAaY8obi2-guN8Y0yTrztJJBKe0",
    authDomain: "appangular88.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "appangular88",
    storageBucket: "appangular88.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "725152387599",
    appId: "1:725152387599:web:2f1d40faac1f1281b8c97a",
    measurementId: "G-7BXN0J34QE"
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you share your package.json?

Answer (score 0):

Use ng instead of npm. "ng add @angular/fire"